How can I set up a YouTube video on a WordPress page to play only between 7AM and 8AM, disabling playback for the rest of the time?
I want to add a YouTube video on a WordPress page and I want that video to be played only on 7AM to 8AM and rest of the time the video play will be disabled. How to do that?

Use the following javascript code to fulfill your requirements.
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
        var videoContainer = document.getElementById('youtube-video-container');
        if (currentTime >= 7 && currentTime < 8) {
            // Enable video playback
            videoContainer.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUR_VIDEO_ID_HERE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        } else {
            // Disable video playback
            videoContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Video playback is disabled at this time.</p>';
        }
    };
</script>

